# stream_context_set_params vs. stream_context_set_option

Tags: php, stream

**What The Documentation Says**

From reading php.net it seems to me that stream_context_set_params pretty much does the same thing as stream_context_set_option. ie.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-params.php

```
bool stream_context_set_params ( resource $stream_or_context , array $params )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-option.php

```
bool stream_context_set_option ( resource $stream_or_context , array $options )
```

`stream_context_set_option` supports additional parameters that `stream_context_set_params` doesn't but otherwise it seems like they're doing the same thing. At least in theory.

**What My Tests Show**

My own testing would suggest otherwise and actually leaves me wondering what `stream_context_set_params` actually does (if anything).

Using `stream_context_set_params`...

```
<?php
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_params($ctx, array('zz' => array('zz' => 'zz')));
print_r(stream_context_get_options($ctx));
```

That prints out the following (which surprises me):

```
Array
(
)
```

Using `stream_context_set_option`...

```
<?php
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, array('zz' => array('zz' => 'zz')));
print_r(stream_context_get_options($ctx));
```

That prints out the following (as I'd expect):

```
Array
(
    [zz] => Array
        (
            [zz] => zz
        )

)
```

So I really have no clue. Any ideas?

Comment: Anybody have a simple answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

`bool stream_context_set_params ( resource $stream_or_context , array $params )`

on this time it's just take 'notification' param key, and used by `stream_notification_callback`.

you can see the list of Supported Context Parameters here:
http://php.net/manual/en/context.params.php

```
<?php $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
        ),
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    stream_context_set_params($context
        , ['notification' => 'your_call_back_notification']
    );


    var_dump(stream_context_get_params($context));
```

Output:

```
Array(
[notification] => your_call_back_notification
[options] => Array
    (
        [http] => Array
            (
                [method] => GET
                [header] => Accept-language: en
                            Cookie: foo=bar

            )

    )
)
```

You may have an warning error for notification call back, it must be a valid callable.
look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-notification-callback.php for more info.