# stream_notification_callback doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, stream

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-notification-callback.php

Per that I'd wouldn't expect the following to produce an error:

```
<?php
stream_context_create(array('notification' => 'callback'));
```

...but it does:

```
Warning: stream_context_create(): options should have the form ["wrappername"]["optionname"] = $value in /path/to/file.php on line 2
```

This also produces an error:

```
<?php
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, array('notification' => 'callback'));
```

Ironically, the code in the `stream_notification_callback` example doesn't produce an error. But since it's using `stream_context_set_params` instead of `stream_context_set_option` I'm not convinced it's actually doing anything lol per this:

[stream_context_set_params vs. stream_context_set_option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15749404/569976)

Answer (score 1):

The function waits for an array inside an array, so the code has to be changed to:

```
stream_context_create(array('wrapper' => array ('notification' => 'callback')));
```